# Find all eigenvalues and corresponding eigenvectors for the matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Find all eigenvalues and corresponding eigenvectors for the matrix:
$$
\left(\begin{array}{cr}
0&-1 \\
2&3
\end{array}\right)
$$
Not looking for a answer, but I don't know what an "eigenvalue" is or how to find them. Can anyone help me here with a jump off point to get started?

Comment: Do you have a textbook that you are working from? If so, it should at least mention eigenvalues. Here's the wikipedia link: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors

What kind of context are you working in? Simply giving you the answer or simply showing you a technique to find the answer neglects the theory that underpins the concept of an eigenvectors.

Comment: @1ftw1 Make sure you understanding the basic meaning of the terms "eigenvalue" and "eigenvector" before you try to compute them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To compute the eigenvalues solve $det \begin{pmatrix}0-\lambda&-1\\2&3-\lambda\end{pmatrix}=0$. You will get $\lambda=1,2$. These are the two eigenvalues. For each of these you need to solve the system of equations given by $\begin{pmatrix}0-\lambda&-1\\2&3-\lambda\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\end{pmatrix}$. The non-zero solutions are the eigenvectors.

For example with $\lambda=1$ we have the system given by $\begin{pmatrix}-1&-1\\2&2\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\end{pmatrix}$ which has **a** non zero solution $(1,-1)$.

With $\lambda=2$ we have the system given by $\begin{pmatrix}-2&-1\\2&1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\end{pmatrix}$ which has **a** non zero solution $(1,-2)$.

In this way you have found both eigenvalues and **a** corresponding eigenvector for both.